# Audio Recording returns null

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am trying to record some audio in my app.
i open the audio recorder with an intent for result. But on result, my data is null.
Am i missing something?
Following is my code

```
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Intent intent =
    new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
   startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_RECORDING);
  }});
   }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if(requestCode == RQS_RECORDING){
  savedUri = data.getData();
  Toast.makeText(AndroidIntentAudioRecording.this,
    "Saved: " + savedUri.getPath(),
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}  
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had buggy issues with this, later I wrote my own recorder app based on [this tutorial](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/). It works like a charm for me and recorder is even delivered to client as an add-on in the app I developed for him.

Answer (score 0):

Please reset your ADB [How to attach back the Android emulator to ADB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236120/how-to-attach-back-the-android-emulator-to-adb), sometimes it happens that we are able to view thumnail from emulator but in reality it is not there

**EDITED**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if(requestCode == RQS_RECORDING){
  savedUri = data.getData();
         String[] path = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION};
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(savedUri, path,null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(path[0]);
            String _path = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            System.out.println("path::::"+_path);
  Toast.makeText(AndroidIntentAudioRecording.this,
    "Saved: " + _path,
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

Comment: It is not about adb. I am working on device. when i open the audio recorder, it records and saves on the device. when i hit back button,  it comes on result but intent data is null

Comment: in this case the savedUri is null, since data.getdata() returns null. as i mentioned, when the control comes back to the activity, i get data as null