# Android Emulator not seen in Device Chooser

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a weird problem here. When I start an Emulator, it starts up after sometime but it is not shown in the Android Device Chooser(some times it is shown). Has anyone encountered this situation before?

[Here](http://tinypic.com/r/2ih76ed/6) is a screen shot of the situation. As you can see, one emulator is running on port 5554 (GingerBreadGoogleAPI), but the Device Chooser shows no emulator or device is connected. The cmd `./adb devices` does not list any device.
I am running Linux 3 kernel on Kubuntu OS with 2GB RAM.

One solution (which I do) is to simply start another emulator. But I dont want a solution for the problem, instead I want to know why this is happening.

Comment: Perhaps not everything is up to date. Maybe you should check the SDK Manager to make sure.

Comment: Well i did not install anything more than the SDK platform and Google APIs in the SDK manager. But im not sure if that would cause a problem. Strangely this problem does not show up always, sometimes everything is butter-like smooth.

Comment: This one has the screenshot how to restart adb from UI http://stackoverflow.com/a/19348083/422842

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is happening sometimes; I am also facing this issue.

I am always trying kill-server & start-server

You can find  ADB  under  SDK_Folder/platform-tools

First do

```
./adb kill-server
```

then

```
./adb start-server
```

and check

```
./adb devices
```

Comment: You can try Reset ADB also From DDMS>Devices.