# Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) makes android emulator not show up under connected devices

Tags: android, emulation, intel

When I use HAXM with an intel atom cpu for an avd, my avd doesn't show up as a connected device in android studio. This essentially means that everytime I rebuild my project, the emulator has to launch a new emulator instance from scratch instead of running the re-built project on the already running emulator. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reset the adb. Do this by opening android device monitor aka android debug monitor aka ddms and then right clicking the dropdown arrow and then clicking "reset adb". You can also do this in terminal as shown here: [Android Emulator not seen in Device Chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749169/android-emulator-not-seen-in-device-chooser)