# Android AVD not recognizing device but adb does?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Android device chooser can't show my real device.
But device manager recognizes and I use Eclipse Juno,windows 7 and my device nexus 7, and I've already tried command: adb kill server and updating usb driver.

Comment: do you have usb debugging enabled on phone? also go to device manager, click on the nexus 7 device and then update driver, there should be different versions to choose, you have to choose the ADB nexus 7 driver (and not the other)

Comment: refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236120/how-to-attach-back-the-android-emulator-to-adb

Comment: yes I have enabled phone and I guess device manager can't recognize nexus 7 because there is no option like nexus 7, just has android device and under this Android Composite ADB interface.

Comment: If you go to device manager, and browse to your Nexus 7, does it have a yellow sign?

Comment: No,Nexus 7 doesn't appear.In device manager just has android device and under this Android Composite ADB interface.For usb driver used google driver when installing Android SDK manager with extras.

Comment: Which deriver I must install?OEM driver or google usb driver(I've already installed).My tablet is nexus 7,os Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Pls update google usb driver.

link:http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

this link will help to solve the issue.

```
Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select Manage.
Select Device Manager in the left pane of the Computer Management window.
Locate and expand Android Phone in the right pane.
Right-click Android Composite ADB Interface and select Update Driver. This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
Select Install from a list or specific location and click Next.
Select Search for the best driver in these locations; un-check Search removable media; and check Include this location in the search.
Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in <sdk>\extras\google\usb_driver\.)
Click Next to upgrade the driver.
```