# Eclipse - Android - Cannot debug

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I don't have any problems with running my application, but when I want to debug it's not starting Acticity and I'm not in debug mode.

Uploading TatryAR.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

Installing TatryAR.apk...

Success!

Starting activity com.TatryAR.main.MainActivity on device emulator-5554

and that's all - nothing starts. 
I can click apk and it works, but not in debug mode.
I've cleaned projects - Project > Clean
I've change debug configuration - Launching default activity to particular activity, always prompt to pick devices  and automatically pick.
I've clicked and unclicked Skip breakpoint
Also restarted Eclipse and Windows also

Comment: hmm.. you set breakpoint?

Comment: Yes, I set breakpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the debugger to an existing process in Eclipse by choosing the process from the device window and clicking on the attach debugger button.
See this post for further details:
[How to attach back the Android emulator to ADB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2236120/346232)

Comment: Attaching back emulator didn't help but debugging an existing process works fine and at the moment I am happy with that workaround. Thanks